# Get Future date for time

Tags: java

I have a time in 24 hour format "14:00:00".
For this date i want to generate date like if current time is less then 14:00:00 then today's date else next day's date.

so for "14:00:00" 
if current date time is "30-10-2012 13:00:00" than I want 30-10-2012
else if current date time is "30-10-2012 15:00:00" than I want 31-10-2012

I tried this method that gives today's date

```
public static String GetTodayDateTimeStamp(String time)
{
    String toReturn = "";

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String toDayDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    toReturn = toDayDate + " " + time;

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Agree with Brian... what have you tried? Btw, I would suggest using Joda Time (http://joda-time.sf.net) for all of this. You should also think about what time zone you're interested in.

Comment: Look at SimpleDateFormat class on how to parse the input you have, how to extract the date from that and do comparison. If you still are stuck, then you can probably come back and update the question with your code and the problem.

Comment: I added a method that gives today's date only, how can i compare time only and get future date

Comment: I get the feeling that 14:00 is the beginning of the day in a certain time zone. If so, you should shift your thinking. Instantiate a Joda-Time DateTime object set to that time zone. Calling [`withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) gives you the first moment of that day, in the local sense. And create a new question on StackOverflow when you get clear enough to write a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new `Date` object, the current time will be assigned to it. If you create two of those objects and set the hour to 14 and the minutes, seconds (and milliseconds if you must) to 0 with the use of a `Calendar` instance you'll have the two dates you have to compare:

```
Date now = new Date();
Date today14pm = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(today14PM);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTES, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECONDS, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECONDS, 0);
today14pm = Calendar.getTime();

if(now.after(today14pm)) {
    //Generate tomorrow's date    
} else {
    //Generate today's date
}
```

Just in case, you might want to set the `lenient` attribute of the calendar to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ten hours to the current date and get the year, month, day parts.

Edit: A more generic answer.

1. Get the time part and add 1 second to it. Let it be "t".
2. Then substract it from the current date and add 1 day to the result. Let it be "d".
3. Then get the year, month, and day parts of "d".

So for example, let time be 10:00:00 instead of 14:00:00. So if you substract it from "today 10:00:01", you get "today 00:00:01". Then add 1 day (or 24 hours) to it, you get "tomorrow 00:00:01".

Comment: That would work only for `14:00:00` right? Please post a generic answer.

Comment: Don't reinvent wheels (especially if they become quadratic as in this case), if there is already a good wheel lying around...

Comment: Ok then, you can share the wheels lying around so we can benefit from them.